# How to redirect url on homepage in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to redirect this page mysite.com/product.php(.*) to mysite.com/home.php
but it is redirecting it on e.g mysite.com/home.php?id=201

mean it redirect mysite.com/product.php?id=201 to mysite.com/home.php?id=201

Where is the problem...?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product\.php /home.php? [R=301,L]
```

The question mark at the end will remove the query string.